# hostapd on Debian Linux opens WLAN Hotspot, but I can't connect to it

Tags: debian, wlan, hostapd, wifi-hotspot

I have a Debian Wheezy machine with `hostapd` running. I want it to make a WPA2-PSK secured WLAN Hotspot. I can see the Hotspot from my Android phone, but every time I try to connect to it, it shows *"Getting IP-Address"* for a very long time, and then it says *"avoided weak web connection"* (*"Schwache Internetverbindung gemieden"*).

My `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` file contains the following:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
###############################
# Basic Config
###############################
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
# Most modern wireless drivers in the kernel need driver=nl80211
driver=nl80211
##########################
# Local configuration...
##########################
interface=wlan0
#bridge=br0
hw_mode=g
channel=1
ssid=HereIsMySSID
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=HereIsMyPassphrase
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

If I change the `wpa_key_mgmt` to `WPA2-PSK`, I get the following error:

```
# hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf 
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Line 22: invalid key_mgmt 'WPA2-PSK'
FT (IEEE 802.11r) requires nas_identifier to be configured as a 1..48 octet string
2 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
#
```

My `hostapd` version is:

```
# hostapd -v
hostapd v1.0
User space daemon for IEEE 802.11 AP management,
IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP/RADIUS Authenticator
Copyright (c) 2002-2012, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors
#
```

How can I make this working?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're missing a DHCP server.

If you haven't set one up, that's why it's getting stuck on "Getting IP-Address"

Eg. https://wiki.debian.org/DHCP_Server

Comment: I get this error: `[FAIL] Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpd[....] check syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!`

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to make a WPA2-PSK connection

```
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
```

is where the mistake. Rename it to

```
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
```

If it doesn't work, I would spend more time tweaking the configuration.

Comment: This shows me the error `Line 22: invalid key_mgmt 'WPA2-PSK'`

Comment: And what do you mean with _I would spend more time tweaking the configuration_?

Comment: I meant taking a deeper look into your hostapd: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd setup configuration. Make sure you restart the wifi and services before you make another attempt to connect via wifi.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a DHCP server, you can follow a tutorial to configure `isc-dhcp-server` or  `udhcpd` with hostapd.

And to test that your AP works, you can just try to connect with a Static IP address.

*NOTE: You won't have an internet connection if you don't configured Nat and forwarding on Iptables :D*

EDIT : I saw that you're using isc-dhcp-server, it says that you need to look in syslog (This file is located in /var/log/syslog and it's the most important log of your system, everything is logged here, from ssh auth fail, to kernel error refer to -> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog).
So to look in syslog for isc-dhcp-server errors just type `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e isc-dhcp-server -e dhcpd` and show us the result :D

Comment: unfortunately I asked this question a few years ago and cannot provide you my syslog. I'm currently using [this script in ArchLinux user repository](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/create_ap-git) which is working quite well (yep I changed operating system in the meantime)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it gets stuck on "Getting IP-Address" is because nothing is giving it an IP address. In order for you to assign IP addresses, you will need to have a DHCP server. The quickest and easiest way I know of to set one up for a wifi-hotspot is to actually use dnsmasq:

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

Once that is done you need to edit /etc/dnsmasq.conf and make sure it has the following settings

```
no-resolv
interface=wlan0 # or whatever wifi card you're using for the AP
dhcp-range=192.168.0.20,192.168.0.50,12h
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

Save and exit.

Restart dnsmasq:

```
sudo service dnsmasq restart
```